# Handling pop-up with different Browsers using WatiN

Tags: watin

I am working with automating a Sharepoint application with WatiN. There are few screen where clicking on button or link additional information will be displayed in a light box pop

The Browser URL and Pop-up Url are different, hence am not able to get the any reference of the objects.

Please help me out with this, all most all of my scripts will need to handle these kind of light boxes.

Answer (score 2):

If your popup is, as I understand them, a page displayed in a new browser window, you will need to create a new WatiN browser instance to access this "popup".

WatiN offer multiple matching criteria to attach a browser using the method AttachTo(). It must be combine with a search specifier:

- By URL : Find.ByURL()
- By URI : Find.ByURI()
- By Windows Title : Find.ByTitle()
- By Window Handle : Find.By()

Here's an  example for attaching a WatiN IE browser to an existing page, in this case your popup, using his window title :

```
IE myPopup = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("My Popup title"));
```

The search by title can use only a portion of the name. Following the same example as the previous one, the following should also match your popup :

```
IE myPopup = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("My Popup"));
```

As for the find by URL or URI, they may work the same way with a partial match (I'm speculate). So if you know what is the URL the popup open, it may be a better solution. Especially if the URL is more unique than your popup title, you'll reduce the chance to attach to a wrong browser.

Comment: Hi, Not exactly. The pop-up is not opening up a new browser. Just the pop-up is present in a new URL but in the existing Browser. Unfortunately i am not able to upload the screen shots here. Hope my question is clear

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is your popup. An iFrame, an new element that is shown, a new tab,..?

Comment: We have used Share Point 2010 open dialog box to show the pop-up. We are able to open the pop-up in Watin during test. But unable to access the controls present in pop-up. Any idea on how to access the controls present in pop-up through Watin?

Comment: We have used Share Point 2010 open dialog box to show the pop-up. We are able to open the pop-up in Watin during test. But unable to access the controls present in pop-up. Any idea on how to access the controls present in pop-up through Watin?

Comment: If your pop-up is a modal dialog, similar to using something like jQuery dialog, then the mark-up is added to the page which means any controls in the modal should be accessible from within your current browser session.

Comment: Also, in our WatiN project here, I added a Modal object to handle testing the common functionality when a modal is open on a page.